# Can you calculate a p value of less than .05 with an Eta-squared equal to 0?

Tags: p-value

This is a question for a study guide I can't quite wrap my head around. My thinking is that if Eta-squared is equal to 0, the between group deviations must be equal to 0, therefore it is impossible to have any evidence against the null (thus a p value of < .05). Is my thinking correct? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to compute $\eta^2$ is:

$$\eta^2=\frac{SS_{Between}}{SS_{Total}}$$

So the only way for $\eta^2$ to be equal to 0 is for $SS_{Between}$ (the numerator) to be 0. In this case, the *F* test for this effect is:

$$F=\frac{SS_{Between}/df_{Between}}{SS_{Within}/df_{Within}}=\frac{0/df_{Between}}{SS_{Within}/df_{Within}}=0$$

Ultimately, the *F* test is necessarily 0, so your reasoning is correct--you can't get a *p* < .05 if $\eta^2=0$, because it implies that $SS_{Between}=0$, and thus that $F=0<F_{critical}$.

Comment: Unless the sample is huge, and eta-squared is 0.00000001, which is printed as 0.